# Images on my Django website are not loading

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am having images on my menu template which when clicked I want to redirect to another template in Django

```
**Below is my code for the menu template:**

 {%for count in item%}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 menu-wrap">
            <div class="heading-menu text-center ftco-animate">
                <h3>{{count.supper}}</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="menus d-flex ftco-animate">
          <div class="menu-img img" style="background-image: url({{count.pic.url}});"></div>
          <div class="text">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="one-half">
                  <h3>{{count.name}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="one-forth">
                  <span class="price">${{count.price}}</span>
                </div>
```

How can i make this happen ?
Can an onclick event be applied?

**Model.py code:**

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

```
class Breakfast(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    ingredients = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100),size=8)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")


class Lunch(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    ingredients = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100),size=8)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
```

Comment: post your model code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put the image directly instead of background

```
<div class="menu-img img">
  <a href="{% url 'whatdoyouwant' %}">
    <img src="{{count.pic.url}}"></img>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: surely it works ! but that way my template get ruined.

Comment: can we have any other alternative ?

Comment: Thanks allot Meryem !  I added the <a href> tag before the original img tag and it worked